# Playing TimeLapse on Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, timelapse

I have just downloaded TimeLapse: Ancient Civilizations on my Windows 7 professional, 32 bit computer. The game is working but the graphics are poor. (My graphics are great on other games.) I was also having crashes, but I think I have fixed those. I am playing in compatibility mode of Windows XP Service Pack 2 and "Run with 256 colors. Is there another mode I should be playing in, or should I install Windows XP mode and play it in that? Completely lost on where to proceed with it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried unchecking "Run with 256 colors"?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still patchy.

Comment: some old games require visual designs to be disabled and/or the desktop resolution reduced, e.g. to 640 x 480.. you might want to try that.

Comment: Try ending the explorer.exe process and then running the game, that is known to fix some old game visual issues.

Comment: It seems to be working fine right now. Unchecked and rechecked 256 colors and unchecked 640X480. I also set up separate memory. The end setup was to have the 256 colors but not the 640X480. Anyway, thanks for your help!